# Need help! A math problem about how to calculate the target value based on 3 or more values given

Tags: math, coordinates, dimensions

Known conditions:

1.a,b,c,d... is in [m,n]..such as [0,1]

2.a,b,c,d...is already know..such as 0.1,0.2,0.3,...

3.There's a thumb inside the given value's 'points'.The value of P is based on the thumb's position

The question is how to get the value of P?

---

There's a simple example is 1d space:

a----(t)------P----(1-t)------b

[1d condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bAtN.png)
The value of t is the 'position' of the thumb.
And the value of P is equal to ta+(1-t)b.

---

What about 2d space? more than 2 points given?
[3 given points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGhj1.png)
[4 given points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMR3r.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a maths problem.

Comment: no...actually it's a graphic problem...maybe how to render ui..so it's a software problem too..

Comment: [Interpolation in an arbitrary quadrilateral](https://www.particleincell.com/2012/quad-interpolation/)